# Custom QTreeView and QFileDialog

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview, qfiledialog

I would like to create a custom `QFileDialog` that has a `QTreeView` with a special behaviour:

I'd like the files in the directory to be represented as 1 file if they belong to such a sequence:

```
file0.jpg
file1.jpg
file2.jpg
...
```

would be represented as only 1 item: `file#.jpg`

Also whenever the user would select `file#.jpg` I'd like the file dialog to return all the associated file names.

After reading all the Qt documentation I find it really hard to pull-off. Does anybody have any idea on how to get started on this?

Comment: Are you new to a model-view paradigm? If so, you should try to write a small test app, using `QTableView` first - it's easier for understanding, 'cause items in table do not depend on parents. All you need to do is inherit `QAbsrtactItemModel` and implement several virtual methods.

Comment: Yeah I never used this framework before. Don't you think it be easier to inherit QFileSystemModel and make some changes to the virtual functions instead of deriving QAbstractItemModel and repeat 90% of the code that's already inside QFileSystemModel?

Comment: That could work. Have you tried it? Where did you stuck?

Comment: I'm now trying to build a small test app, i'll comment back when i'm done

Comment: okay I'm now stuck : how can I retrieve somehow a list of all the elements in a column? I'd like to be able to count them with a condition I'm looking at QAbstractItemModel::headerData but I can't seem to understand it

Comment: What elements are you talking about? Header elements or data elements?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30616/discussion-between-lex-and-amartel)

Comment: I'm still stuck on the matter